# How to enable Direct Browsing on IIS-8

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, cmd, server, iis-8

Hello all i am just learning bootstrap from edx and making my lab1 on VS , but when i tried to open it in browser to see my designed web , It says me 
"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory"
I tried everything i have enabled it from windows features it has no effect 
i also tried this cmd command still no effect

```
appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

[image]

what should i do now ? Furthermore i am using windows-8 and VS12, Any help would be highly appreciated

The localHost show me this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space before the second slash.

Comment: Still not succeed ! it says that its not supported :/

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding my issue @SLaks

Answer (score 0):

first sure in your iis rule install directory browsing 
or

```
servermanagercmd -install Web-Dir-Browsing
```

and your syntax not corrected

```
appcmd set config (url) /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

when you want enable directory browsing which of your site means!
for see (url) or your sites you should query through appcmd like

```
appcmd list site
```

for example

```
appcmd set config "default web site" /section:directorybrowse /enabled:true
```